# Unable to output formatted HTML from Jquery with html DataType

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I am calling some data which has pre-formatted HTML code in it, but when it renders from the jquery it appears to ignore my markup. This is my jQuery:

```
function GetFeed(){
   document.getElementById("marq").innerHTML = '';

   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "xmlproxy.ashx",    
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(obj) {        
       $('<span class="tickerItem"></span>').html(obj).appendTo('#marq');
    }
   });
}
```

Comment: What do you see when you `alert(obj);` in the success function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong just do:

```
$("#marq").append(your_html);
```

Comment: I just tried it but unfortunately that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: then it's probably not returning anything, have you used firebug to check what the post is returning?

Comment: sorry my friend, i used the sniffer and saw that the data i was passing in must have stripped out the markup. your recommendation was fine. cheers